# LDO peak-to-peak voltage 280mV

Tags: ldo

I have an LD1117V33 connected to a 12V powersupply. When I plug the output to my osciloscope I see about 280mv peak-to-peak voltage, sometime more.

Is it normal? Is there anything I can do to improve it?

My circuit is pretty simple. 12V - LDO - Output with 2 capacitors in parallel in input and output. 100nF input and 10uF output.

[image]

Comment: Is the glitch periodical ? Are you sure that your 12v is stable ?

Comment: what is the load current? type of load?

Comment: No load, straight to the oscilloscope.

Comment: Is the 12V power supply linear or switch mode? Is the 12V power supply earthed? Is the oscilloscope earthed?

Comment: @MathieuG. good point. didn't check.. Let check

Comment: Looks like 12v is similar https://imgur.com/a/Kuu6d2V

Comment: @Justme, switch mode. not earthed. oscilloscope is earthed

Comment: What you see is most likely the switching of the 12V then. Verify it by looking at regulator input and output simultaneously with two probes.

Comment: @LD1117 The minimum load current can be as high as 5 mA. So put about 1-2 k ohm load on the output side. Try then to measure the variations.

Comment: Try lower inductance ground connection from scope probes to regulator, or try differential measurement from 12V output with two probes, so that two probe grounds are connected together but not to the ground of 12V supply.

Comment: @jonk load didn't help

Comment: @LD1117 okay. Was just a thought.

Comment: @Justme you are right. Here is the input and output of the regulator: https://imgur.com/a/bdjj1NL (Yellow output, purple input)

Comment: @jonk np. thanks :)

Comment: Q!: What caps in and out Q2 What cap types? Q3 Have you matched the data sheet spec re caps? || Use ground clip on oscilloscope probe and connect with short lead to ground as near to LDO ground as possible. | Ensure input and output caps meet spec as per LDO data sheet. They may need to be within a certain uF range and MAY need resistors in series with the caps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the spikes are present on both 12V input and 3.3V output, so they come from the 12V switching mode power supply that is ungrounded.

The switching spikes couple capacitively from the mains side to the isolated 12V side, and the charging currents loop via oscilloscope probe ground wire back to mains earth. The voltage bounce comes from inductance of the scope probe ground lead which is not able to handle fast currents.

So part of the issue is how the probes are connected.